# DB2 TRUNCATE command - DROP STORAGE option

Tags: db2, storage, truncate

I performed action `TRUNCATE TABLE TABLENAME IMMEDIATE;` but I did not used DROP STORAGE option. I read that it is default option if it is not put.
It was not so big table regarding table space but I am still interested if command I executed released database disk space on the server or not? I am not able to conculde that based on current disk space.

I would like confirmation for this?
Also I would like to know did I have to do `DB2 REORG` for this table after the TRUNCATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIST TABLESPACES SHOW DETAIL` to check the High Water Mark. If it still appears high, you can always issue an `ALTER TABLESPACE <tablespace> REDUCE MAX` (assuming you are on automatic storage). The commands for old-style DMS are a litte different.

I have [another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41577/why-doesnt-delete-reorg-free-diskspace-db2/41584#41584) where I list that information

Comment: Hi Chris, please can you tell me if I did not use DROP STORAGE option was it used by default by the system or not? and should DB2 REORG be run or not after doing the truncate or database server is smart enough to handle fragment parts on that before after the truncate?

Comment: IBM Knowledge Center shows that DROP STORAGE is the default: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053474.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-238&lang=en

Comment: It may not be a bad idea to run REORGS and RUNSTATS and a reset of the high water mark after a large removal of data. Occasionally, DB2 will not release the disk back to the OS and you need to run those commands to make it do so.

Comment: Hi Chris.. thank you..ok I will run  Db2 runstats on table TABLENAME on key columns and indexes all and also DB2 REORG TABLE TABLENAME

Comment: @ChrisAldrich If you `TRUNCATE` a table, `REORG` is unnecessary.  What is left to reorg?

Comment: The disk may or may not be released back to OS. REORG just helps clean things up. And REDUCE MAX helps the tablespace to release the disk back to the OS. I'm not saying it has to be done all the time. High Water Mark just needs to be watched is all.

Comment: Just to add that without executing the command ALTER TABLESPACE <tablespace> REDUCE MAX space was not released so thank you once again!